# Email HTML form submissions with csv file attachment - receiving multiple emails

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I've been asked to create a form that on submission sends the admin an email with a .csv attachment of the collated data.

I've scoured the internet and found this solution, and it works! However on submission I get about 3-4 emails (it seems to vary). Is this the code, or am I already receiving spam?

HTML Form:

```
      <form method="post">
            <p>Enter your email address
            <input type="text" name="email" size="50" />
            </p>
            <p>Please add your first name
            <input type="text" name="firstName" size="20" />
            </p>
            <p>Please add your last name
            <input rows="2" name="lastName" size="20"></input>
            </p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2" />
            </p>
        </form>
```

PHP Code:

```
        <?php

            $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
            $firstName=$_REQUEST['firstName'];
            $lastName=$_REQUEST['lastName'];


            $to = "test@testmail.co.uk";


            $subject = "Test subject";

            $message = "".
            "Email: $email" . "\n" .
            "First Name: $firstName" . "\n" .
            "Last Name: $lastName";

            //The Attachment

            $cr = "\n";
            $data = "Email" . ',' . "First Name" . ',' . "Last Name" . $cr;
            $data .= "$email" . ',' . "$firstName" . ',' . "$lastName" . $cr;
            $fp = fopen('diploma_apprenticeship_form_sub.csv','a');
            fwrite($fp,$data);
            fclose($fp);

            $attachments[] = Array(
               'data' => $data,
               'name' => 'diploma_apprenticeship_form_sub.csv',
               'type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
            );


            //Generate a boundary string

            $semi_rand = md5(time());
            $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";


            //Add the headers for a file attachment


            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                       "From: {$from}\n" .
                       "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
                       " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";


            //Add a multipart boundary above the plain message


            $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
                      "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                      "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
                      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
                      $text . "\n\n";


            //Add sttachments

            foreach($attachments as $attachment){
               $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment['data']));
               $name = $attachment['name'];
               $type = $attachment['type'];

               $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                          "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
                          " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
                          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                          $data . "\n\n" ;
            }

            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

            ?>
```

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: Try following this guide  http://phptutorialforall.blogspot.it/2011/07/send-email-with-multiple-attachments-in.html

Comment: Try to test it with 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 attachements and check if the number of attachments has any relation with the number of emails you are receiving

Comment: @verdesrobert I only have one attachment and I'm getting 3-4 emails, but I'll see if adding more increases this number

Comment: I think the problem is not in the php code

Comment: @verdesrobert yep that tutorial isn't quite what I'm after but there isn't much difference in the php code so I don't think that's the issue either ..

Comment: try to send to another email

Comment: @verdesrobert tried that

Comment: @verdesrobert same as before. I think I've worked out the issue, it seems to send an email on page entry and then on form submission. I went into a new browser and entered in the url and it sent an email before I'd even submitted the form. Any ideas on that theory?

Comment: can you post the entire php page?

Comment: @verdesrobert sorted it - I just added an if statement that says if the email field equals nothing don't send any emails. This stops the email being triggered when the page is loaded, and an email when the page resets after submission - hence why I was getting 3 emails!

Comment: Write the solution as an answer and mark it as the right answer so the question will not remain marked as unanswered

Comment: @verdesrobert is that what everyone is supposed to do when they answer their own question? Thought it was kinda bad form to do that.

Comment: it's one way to make the question solved :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just added an if statement that says if the email field equals nothing don't send any emails. This stops the email being triggered when the page is loaded, and an email when the page resets after submission - hence why I was getting 3 emails!